# errors register and login in one page laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I use standard make:auth authentification in Laravel 5.4 I did some modifications with routes. And I see the same errors with email and password on loginform and registerform on my page. I have this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the errors that you see? Also, can we get a list of the changes you made to the routes that may affect this?

Comment: web.php `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`     It doesnt matter, I edit views. I have post forms with route('login') and route('register') in one page. And  I have the same $errors in two forms

Comment: For example, "The email field is required."

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `auth.register` view.